# Apache Camel consumer template to copy file, cannot copy one file twice

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I am using apache camel 2.15.2. I have got a consumer template so that I can copy file with dynamic file names:

```
if (fileInfo != null) {
            filename = fileInfo.getFileName();
            String camelUri = "file://" + fileInfo.getCopyFilePath() + "/?fileName=RAW("
                    + filename + ")&noop=false&idempotent=false&readLock=changed";
            System.out.println("Camel uri: " + camelUri);
            logger.info("Camel uri: " + camelUri);

            Exchange ex = consumerTemplate.receive(camelUri);
....
```

As you can see, I have set noop, and idempotent explicitly to achieve copying same file more than once. But, it does not do that. It hangs on receive method for subsequent tries to copy a file with same name. It can copy that, only if we restart the application. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. It might be something similar to this [issue](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1504643), but I do not have access to that solution. Thanks in advance.

When I debugged through Camel code, it seems, it is calling EventDrivenPollingConsumer's receive method, and hangs when calls queue.take() (line 110, [EventDrivenPollingConsumer](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/camel/impl/EventDrivenPollingConsumer.html)). And, even inside that, 'count' variable is zero in ArrayBlockingQueue:

```
while (count == 0)
                notEmpty.await();
```

Added this, just in case it helps anyone having a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, If I call 'consumerTemplate.doneUoW(ex)', it does copy multiple times. But, at the same time it was deleting (actually moving to .camel folder) the source file, which I did not want to! Then, had to set noop=true:

```
if (fileInfo != null) {
        filename = fileInfo.getFileName();
        String camelUri = "file://" + fileInfo.getCopyFilePath() + "/?fileName=RAW("
                + filename + ")&noop=true&idempotent=false&readLock=none";
        System.out.println("Camel uri: " + camelUri);
        logger.info("Camel uri: " + camelUri);

        Exchange ex = consumerTemplate.receive(camelUri);
        // consumerTemplate.r
        logger.info("File received: " + fileInfo.getFileName());
        exchange.getOut().setBody(ex.getIn().getBody());

        consumerTemplate.doneUoW(ex);
    }
```

Now, it works as expected.